# Is it incorrect to use "I'm" to replace "I am." when that is the whole sentence?

Tags: usage

Is it incorrect to use *I'm.* to replace *I am.* when that is the whole sentence?

> Are you going to the beach?
>
> I'm.

I haven't ever seen or heard *I'm* used this way. Is it technically incorrect?

Comment: When the am is stressed it will not shorten to 'm (same for all contractions). In this sentence the am will inevitably be stressed so you will not get contraction.

Comment: That makes sense. What qualifies as the "am" being stressed; Is it just because that's where the emphasis is being put on the sentence? Or is it because "am" is the main verb (sure there is a more proper word for "main" verb), as opposed to "I am going"?

Comment: [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction “it's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its)

Comment: I don't know that it is strictly incorrect but it would be very odd and might not be recognised for what it is. The difficulty with it is that in normal use the 'am' in the shortened for is not emphasised because it is another part of the sentence which carries the emphasis (eg "I'm going to the _beach_") whereas in the short sentence (in fact the shortest in English)  the word "am" is emphasised.

Comment: In ordinary / unmarked sentences, the general rule is that the sentence stress falls on the last word that represents new information. More specifically it falls on the syllable of that word that takes the lexical stress (i.e. the stress that is marked in the dictionary).

Comment: I think it's incorrect "technically" or otherwise. But you can use "I'm" as in "I'm not".

Comment: Re my first comment, *same for all contractions* is an overstatement as you will see from Tinfoil Hat's link.

Comment: It's not just a matter of stress. Consider _Isn't **anybody** going to talk to him?_ _**I** am._ _Am_ is not stressed (at least, not relative to _I_) , but cannot be contracted.

Comment: Consider how many times you have heard a contraction as the entire sentence -- he'd; she'd; we'd; you'd. This is never done as far as I know. Contractions exist to shorten otherwise long sentences. If the entire sentence is "I am", then there is no need for a contraction.